# Why are the namespaces Jackson serializes into XML structured incorrectly

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jaxb

I am trying to serialize an object into XML using Jackson's XmlMapper.  I want it to have namespaces in appropriate areas.  When I serialize the object, however, every attribute is having a namespace - attributes that are directly part of the class I'm trying to serialize will have an xmlns="", and each attribute on referenced classes contains their own namespace prefix (rather than a single prefix for the whole referenced class).

I'm using Jackson 2.9.8

The main class I want to serialize:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name",
        "objectDescription",
        "exampleFieldClass"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ExampleClass", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto")
public class ExampleClass
{

    @XmlElementRef(name = "name", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> name;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "objectDescription", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> objectDescription;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "exampleFieldClass", namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<ExampleFieldClass> ExampleFieldClass;

    public JAXBElement<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(JAXBElement<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public JAXBElement<String> getObjectDescription() {
        return objectDescription;
    }

    public void setObjectDescription(JAXBElement<String> objectDescription) {
        this.objectDescription = objectDescription;
    }

    public JAXBElement<ExampleFieldClass> getExampleFieldClass() {
        return ExampleFieldClass;
    }

    public void setExampleFieldClass(JAXBElement<ExampleFieldClass> ExampleFieldClass) {
        this.ExampleFieldClass = ExampleFieldClass;
    }
}
```

A special type:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ExampleFieldClass", namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto", propOrder = {
        "id", "dtoType"
})
public class ExampleFieldClass {

    @XmlElement(name = "id", namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto")
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "dtoType", namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto")
    protected String dtoType;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDtoType() {
        return dtoType;
    }

    public void setDtoType(String dtoType) {
        this.dtoType = dtoType;
    }
}
```

The XmlMapper config and a test:

```
public class ExampleTest {

    private final ExampleObjectFactory factory = new ExampleObjectFactory();

    @Test
    public void testSerialize() throws Exception {
        XmlMapper mapper = getXmlMapper();

        ExampleFieldClass exampleFieldClass = new ExampleFieldClass();
        exampleFieldClass.setDtoType("dtoType");
        exampleFieldClass.setId("id");

        ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass.setName(factory.createExampleClassName("name"));
        exampleClass.setObjectDescription(factory.createExampleClassObjectDescription("description"));
        exampleClass.setExampleFieldClass(factory.createExampleClassExampleFieldClass(exampleFieldClass));

        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(exampleClass);
        System.out.println(serialized);
    }

    private XmlMapper getXmlMapper() {
        JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        module.addSerializer(JAXBElement.class, new JsonSerializer<JAXBElement>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(JAXBElement value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                if (value.isNil()) {
                    gen.writeNull();
                } else {
                    gen.writeObject(value.getValue());
                }
            }
        });

        XmlMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());

        objectMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        return objectMapper;
    }

    @XmlRegistry
    public static class ExampleObjectFactory {

        @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", name = "name", scope = ExampleClass.class)
        public JAXBElement<String> createExampleClassName(String value) {
            QName _ExampleClassName_QNAME = new QName("urn:ExampleClass.dto", "name");
            return new JAXBElement<>(_ExampleClassName_QNAME, String.class, ExampleClass.class, value);
        }

        @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", name = "objectDescription", scope = ExampleClass.class)
        public JAXBElement<String> createExampleClassObjectDescription(String value) {
            QName _ExampleClassObjectDescription_QNAME = new QName("urn:ExampleClass.dto", "objectDescription");
            return new JAXBElement<>(_ExampleClassObjectDescription_QNAME, String.class, ExampleClass.class, value);
        }

        @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto", name = "ExampleFieldClass", scope = ExampleFieldClass.class)
        public JAXBElement<ExampleFieldClass> createExampleClassExampleFieldClass(ExampleFieldClass value) {
            QName _ExampleClassExampleFieldClass_QNAME = new QName("urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto", "ExampleFieldClass");
            return new JAXBElement<>(_ExampleClassExampleFieldClass_QNAME, ExampleFieldClass.class, ExampleClass.class, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual XML output is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ExampleClass xmlns="urn:ExampleClass.dto">
    <name xmlns="">name</name>
    <objectDescription xmlns="">description</objectDescription>
    <exampleFieldClass xmlns="">
        <wstxns1:id xmlns:wstxns1="urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto">id</wstxns1:id>
        <wstxns2:dtoType xmlns:wstxns2="urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto">dtoType</wstxns2:dtoType>
    </exampleFieldClass>
</ExampleClass>
```

The namespaces shouldn't be defined on every attribute, nor should there be ones defined as an empty String.

Something to note:  the empty namespaces xmlns="" will not be there if I change the attribute annotations to @XmlElement; however, it will no longer handle JaxbElement properly (empty vs null).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong for this?

Comment: Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: well... I managed to at least simplify things.  2 questions: 1. do I edit the question and replace everything? 2. do I include imports?

Comment: 1) Yes. --- 2) Not necessary, since you've named the libraries you use, but you can, for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after digging into jaxb/jackson/spring/google... a lot... I found the `XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector`.  This class will look at the JAXB annotations on whatever classes are being serialized to determine information such as simple name, namespace, propOrder, etc.  The problem lies in the `findNamespace` and `findRootName` methods.

`findNamespace(Annotated ann)`: there's 2 problems here.  The first is, when it tries to determine the namespace of a Class, it will only look for the `XmlRootElement` annotation.  It will not look for other annotations that may contain namespace (in my case, `XmlType`).  The same issue applies for the `XmlElementRef` annotation - the current method will look for `XmlElement` and `XmlAttribute` to determine the namespace; it does not look for `XmlElementRef`.

`findRootName(Annotated ann)`: similar to the `findNamespace` issue, this will only look at the `XmlRootElement` when trying to find the namespace.  For our situation, again, that does not exist and we need it to look at the `XmlType` annotation.

The solution that I have, and please let me know if there's a reason it should not be doing this, was to extend from the `XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector`, creating my own implementation that overrides `findNamespace` and `findRootName`.  Each method is essentially the same, except that it also adds the search for the `XmlType` annotation and `XmlElementRef` annotation.  Once this is created, just add it to the object mapper using:

```
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomXmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector());
```

Something to note, for anyone who might read this and have an additional issue that I ran into, `propOrder` doesn't seem to handle inheritance by default.  Therefore, if you have a parent class that has a `propOrder`, those attributes will not be first in your serialized xml.  To get around this, in that `CustomXmlJaxbAnnotationInstrospector` class, also override the `findSerializationPropertyOrder(AnnotatedClass annotatedClass)` - in here, you can loop through the super classes (up until Object.class), and prepend each set of props to a new list/String[] that will contain them all.

Answer (score 1):

If you change definition of ExampleClass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name",
        "objectDescription",
        "exampleFieldClass"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ExampleClass", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto")
public class ExampleClass
{
    
    @XmlElement(name = "name", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", required = false)
    protected String name;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "objectDescription", namespace = "urn:ExampleClass.dto", required = false)
    protected String objectDescription;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "exampleFieldClass", namespace = "urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto", required = false)
    protected ExampleFieldClass ExampleFieldClass;

}
```

And change creation of ExampleClass instance:

```
    XmlMapper mapper = getXmlMapper();

    ExampleFieldClass exampleFieldClass = new ExampleFieldClass();
    exampleFieldClass.setDtoType("dtoType");
    exampleFieldClass.setId("id");

    ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
    exampleClass.setName("name");
    exampleClass.setObjectDescription("description");
    exampleClass.setExampleFieldClass(exampleFieldClass);

    String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(exampleClass);
```

Output will be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ExampleClass xmlns="urn:ExampleClass.dto">
  <name>name</name>
  <objectDescription>description</objectDescription>
  <wstxns1:exampleFieldClass xmlns:wstxns1="urn:ExampleFieldClass.dto">
    <wstxns1:id>id</wstxns1:id>
    <wstxns1:dtoType>dtoType</wstxns1:dtoType>
  </wstxns1:exampleFieldClass>
</ExampleClass>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this right now.  However, it is something I tried, and the issue there was that it no longer handled the difference between null and JaxbElement(null).  So undefined vs a value of null. Both would be interpreted as purely null when deserializing.

Comment: yeah, this method has no way of differentiating between null and not defined